# changed from jcenter() to mavenCentral() and got missing javax.jms

Tags: java, gradle

Due to jcentral() [shutdown](https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown) so javax.ws.rs doesn't exits:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not determine artifacts for javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1
   > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.$%7Bpackaging.type%7D'.
      > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/javax/ws/rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.$%7Bpackaging.type%7D'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request
```

So i changed my gradle repo from jcenter() to mavenCentral(), and packaged **gradle war** got some errors about missing jms library

Got output error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
> Could not find jms.jar (javax.jms:jms:1.1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar
```

Also checked the URL above, and this **jms** lib is not found.

How can I resolve this, tks in advantage!

Comment: Do you know which dependency is trying to use jms.jar? The javax.jms:jms:1.1 doesn't contain a jar (not even jcenter). It's just a specification. There is only a POM in there. The implementation comes from a supplier like JBoss etc.

Comment: I don't define any jms lib in build.gradle, I also ran gradle --debug but not found any information relate to jms. Maybe this used by other dependencies but Gradle output don't show it

Comment: I ran with jcenter in intelj well, so crazy that got error above from eclipse and console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After test one by one dependency in my build.gradle, i found my legacy dependency oscache that used jms.jar that no exits in maven download:

```
providedCompile group: 'opensymphony', name: 'oscache', version: '2.4.1'
```

OScache hasn't been developed a long time ago, it might used old link in maven to reference jms library. Crazy things is gradle running differently in different environments. It worked well in intelj(with jcentral), event with javax.ws.rs(jcentral) but not the same in eclipse or command line environment.

If i remove this dependency in gradle, it works again. So to solve this issue I must download oscache as local lib.